# jQuery extend an event variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

The plugin has this variable

```
this.onValid = options.onValid || function(){ this.insertMessage(this.createMessageSpan()); this.addFieldClass(); };
```

The problem is,when i define a new instance I want to add a new function to this.onValid, I don't want to override the default events?

How can I extend the variable this.onValid ?

Answer (score 3):

```
this.onValid = options.onValid || function(){ this.insertMessage(this.createMessageSpan()); this.addFieldClass(); };
//That above is already defined;
this._onValid = this.onValid; //Make a backup function
this.onValid = function (){
    this._onValid(); //Call the actual function
    //Your extended code here //Call your code
}
```

That was specific to your code. To understand it better, maybe this example will help:

```
writeA = function (){
    document.write('a');
};
//Now I want to extend the writeA function to write 'b' as well
_writeA = writeA;
writeA = function (){
    _writeA(); //So now I call whatever the function originally did
    document.write('b'); //And now I execute what I want to add to the function
};
```

[Example's demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d9mPW/)

Just tried fixing the code you provided in the comment. Try this:

```
var obj1 = {
    this._onValid = this.onValid; //Do this assuming this.onValid is already defined
    onValid: function(){ //Redefine it
        this._onValid();
        newFunction();
    }

};
```

---

### Edit

From the plugin. Just edit it to look like this:

```
  this.onValid = options.onValid || function(){ this.insertMessage(this.createMessageSpan()); this.addFieldClass(); };
  this._onValid = this.onValid;
  this.onValid = function (){
        this._onValid();
        //YOUR CODE HERE
  };
```

I have edited the original file to look like that [here.](http://pastebin.com/rgPtWeP4)

Hah, just realized I put the same code as I had in the beginning here. Well, that's because that's **exactly** how it should look. See my edited file and search for `//YOUR CODE HERE` and add your code there.

Comment: I get too much recursion error! 

var obj1 = new OBJECT(onValid:
            function(){this._onValid= this.onValid;this._onValid();newFunction();}
       } );

Comment: @user1114371 That's because you *are* having too much recursion. You don't call `_onValid` inside the `onValid` function! I'll edit my answer to make it clearer if you give me some more code. (The object that `this.onValid` is declared in.

Comment: @user1114371 I've edited my answer to try and fix your current code. Try it.

Comment: onValid is declared inside the OBJECT class in the initialize: function.
I'm trying to create a new instance from the class OBJECT,  and extend the function onValid by adding  a new function.
Thank You very much

Comment: @user1114371 It'd still help if I could just see the code for it. Could you give me a link?

Comment: Yes sure, you can download the plugin from here http://livevalidation.com/download  
and All what I'm trying to do is adding a new function to the onValid variable.

Comment: @user1114371 Edited my answer. Also put the [edited code on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/rgPtWeP4) so you can use it directly.